# Using hex values in constants

Tags: hex, vhdl, constants

I am trying to create a few constants and assign hex numbers to them; however, I keep getting errors.

I want the constant `FOO_CONST` to be equal to `0x38`

Like this...

`constant FOO_CONST : integer := x"38";`

The error:

`Type integer does not match with a string literal`

I've tried a few variants with no success.

Comment: Integers don't have bits. The hex value is a bit string literal with a string value equivalent assignable to single dimensional arrays. An integer requires an abstract literal, a based literal of the form `16#38#`. Where 16 is the base, the '#' is a delimiter. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15. Lexical elements, 15.5.3 Based literals. You could also `use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.numeric_std.all;` and `constant FOO_CONST : integer := to_integer(unsigned'(x"38"));`converting a bit string literal to an integer specifying sign extension with the required qualified expression.

Comment: What you probably want is something like:
constant FOO_CONST : unsigned(7 downto 0) := x"38";

One tends to use unsigned or std_logic_vector more often than integer in VHDL for synthesis.

Comment: You could also use the `#` [numeric literal](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/literals.html). If you use it with 16 as the prefix, then it'll accept a base 16 number

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can specify a base for integers by using the format `base#value#`:

```
constant FOO_CONST : integer := 16#38#;
```

Answer (score 8):

In general, you can use literals in expressions as follows:

Numeric literals may be expressed in any base from `2` to `16`. They may also be broken up using underscore, for clarity.

```
FOO_CONST_HEX <= 16#FF#;
FOO_CONST_BIN <= 2#1010_1010#;
FOO_CONST_BROKEN := 1_000_000.0; -- breaking the number using _
```

To **answer the question clearly**, you can do as [Erasmus Cedernaes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4713758/erasmus-cedernaes) suggested:

```
constant FOO_CONST: integer:= 16#38#;
```

OR

```
constant FOO_CONST : std_logic_vector := X"38"; -- if you will convert it to a std_logic_vector later
```

Literals for arrays of characters, such as `string`, `bit_vector` and `std_logic_vector` are placed in double quotes:

```
constant FLAG :bit_vector(0 to 7) := "11111111";
constant MSG : string := "Hello";
```

Numeric literals with a **decimal point** are real, those **without** are integer;

```
constant FREEZE : integer := 32;
constant TEMP : real := 32.0;
```

Real numbers may be expressed in exponential form:

```
FACTOR := 2.2E-6;
```

Literals of type time (and other physical types) must have units. The units should be preceded by a space, although some tools may not require this:

```
constant DEL1 :time := 10 ns;
constant DEL2 :time := 2.27 us;
```

Literals of enumerated types may either be characters (as for `bit` and `std_logic`), or identifiers:

```
type MY_LOGIC is ('X','0','1','Z');
type T_STATE is (IDLE, READ, END_CYC);
signal CLK : MY_LOGIC := '0';
signal STATE : T_STATE := IDLE;
```

Bit vector literals may be expressed in binary (default), octal or hex. They may also contain embedded underscores for clarity. These forms may not be used as `std_logic_vector` literals:

```
BIT_8_BUS <= B"1111_1111";
BIT_9_BUS <= O"353";
BIT_16_BUS <= X"AA55";
```

#### Notice that:

> Literals are supported for synthesis, providing they are of a type
> acceptable to the logic synthesis tool. They are either synthesized as
> connections to logic '1' or '0' or are used to help minimize the
> number of gates required.

[Reference](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ejmoorkan/vhdlref/literals.html)